# Microsoft Access 2010 Web Databases Convert Date to String

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to build a calculated field for a web database in Microsoft Access 2010.

The field should show the day in a three character format as follows:
Mon
Tue
Wed

from an existing date column in the table.

Obviously the Format function is not compatible with the web.  And the following function FormatDateTime does not have the option to convert to a string day, just a long and short date and time.

Any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

If this is not possible my only option seems to be to create a client object.

I have tried adding the function into a query instead but this is also incompatible with a web database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WeekdayName should suit. Be careful with FirstDayofWeek:

```
SELECT WeekdayName(Weekday([ADate],1),-1,1) FROM Table
```

Syntax:

```
Weekday(Date,[FirstDayOfWeek])
WeekdayName(Weekday as Long,[Abbreviate as Boolean],[FirstDayOfWeek])

1 = Sunday in both of the functions.
```